# Regex c# Match Pattern and Ignore matches in quotes

Tags: c#, regex, oracle

I want to be able to find bind variables (start with a colon and then have text) in a SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE TABLE_UID = :TABUID AND TABLE_TEXT = :TEXT
```

I have found that this regular expression works to find bind variables:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(":[\\w]*",
                      RegexOptions.Multiline & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 

foreach (Match m in reg.Matches(sql)) 
{
    bindVar.Add(m.Value); 
}
```

I what I can't figure out is how to ignore potential bind variables that exist in quotes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE TABLE_UID = :TABUID AND TABLE_TEXT = TO_DATE(:TEXT, 'hh:mi:ss')
```

:mi & :ss should not be matched in the regular expression.

Comment: Are you sure that `RegexOptions.Multiline & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is correct? I think it should read `RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little shaky regarding the wisdom of using regular expressions to do what you're trying to do, but if I were you, I'd

- make a copy of your input string
- strip out what you don't want in the input string (in this case, content inside quotes)
- now you don't have to worry about what's in the quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use a word boundary \b

```
\\b:[\\w]*
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match anything that's not enclosed in single quotes:

```
(?<![\\S'])([^'\\s]+)(?![\\S'])
```

I'm not savvy enough to know how to combine it with what you already have though.